# Error al calcular mediana

Tags: java, arraylist

Tengo esa lista `static ArrayList<String> li = new ArrayList<>();`
y quiero sacar la mediana con el siguiente metodo

```
public static double calculateMediana() {
        double mediana;
        Collections.sort(li);        
        int nElementos = li.size();
        if(nElementos % 2 == 0){
            double sumaM = Double.parseDouble(li.get(nElementos))/2 + Double.parseDouble(li.get(nElementos))/2-1 ;
            mediana = sumaM/2;
        }else{
            mediana = Double.parseDouble(li.get(nElementos))/2;
        }
        return mediana;
}
```

]
Al momento de correrlo me marca el siguiente error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, la variable `nElementos` te indica la cantidad de elementos de tu lista. Luego al intentar usar el método `get(nElementos)` estás pidiendo obtener el elemento en el índice equivocado. Si tu lista tiene `nElementos`, los mismos van desde cero hasta `nElementos -1`. Es por eso que te da el error de `IndexOutOfBound` que significa: índice fuera de límite. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Para calcular la "Mediana" primero debes entender como se obtiene:

> **Mediana**: El valor del punto medio de un conjunto de datos para el que
>   un número igual de muestras es menor y mayor que el valor. Para un
>   tamaño de muestra impar, este es el elemento central de la muestra
>   ordenada; para un tamaño de muestra uniforme, este es el promedio de
>   los elementos centrales de la muestra clasificada.

Veo 2 errores a simple vista,
  Primeramente no podrás ordenar correctamente los valores si estos son valores de tipo String, debes cambiarlos a Integer y los podrás ordenar correctamente usando:

```
  Collections.sort(<listado>);
```

El segundo error (que es el que se muestra en el `LogCat`) es que debes obtener los elementos centrales pero no dividiendo el valor entre 2 y entre 2 - 1, ya que lo que debes obtener son los indices de los elementos centrales, para esto puedes obtener los indices de esta forma:

`int indiceCentral1 = nElementos/2` y `int indiceCentral2 = nElementos/2 -1`

Por lo tanto el código correcto sería:

```
public static double calculateMediana() {

        //Realiza un array de enteros a partir del array de Strings       
        List<Integer> lnumeros = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (String s: li){
           lnumeros.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
        }

        double mediana;

        //Ordena
        Collections.sort(lnumeros);        
        int nElementos = lnumeros.size();

        if(nElementos % 2 == 0){  
          double sumaM = lnumeros.get(nElementos/2) + lnumeros.get(nElementos/2-1) ;          
          mediana = sumaM/2;
        }else{
            mediana = lnumeros.get(nElementos/2); 
        }


        return mediana;
}
```